# Convert two-dimensional array in to one dimensional array by summing the values by keys like shown here

Tags: php, arrays, process

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [1] => 111
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [1] => 10
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 111
    )
)
```

I want to convert this array as:

```
array
(
  [17]=>121
  [20]=>111
)
```

is there any php array function which can do it easily. I know the other way, but want to know if any ready made function can do that or not?? 
Please Help.

Here I actually wanted to convert

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [1] => 111
     )
```

17 to key and take 111 as value then in next array

```
 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [1] => 10
    )
```

do the same thing get first value 17 as key and add 10 into previous value 111
which is 121 and then 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 111
        )
take 20 as key and assign value 111 to that key so basically, I want first value as a key and second value as value and for all same keys I want to add values as I stated before.
 I thought there might be any PHP ready-made function for that as I have seen there are lots of array processing functions available in PHP. Now, I realized there is no any such kind of function available. I can do my own custom code for this purpose but was looking for good logical solution.

Comment: Thats a too special. You can only use foreach or array_walk or what ever, where you can describe your target... do you want an example or is that the other known way?

Comment: 1) You're trying to convert a *two-dimensional* array into a *one-dimensional* one. 2) Please *spell out* that you're trying to **sum** the values by key; don't let us guess that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No builtin function for that but it is a simple foreach loop. Assume your array is stored in variable $arr;

```
$return = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $return[$a[0]] += $a[1];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($return);
```

if you are calling multiple times then you can easily write your own function

```
$arr[0]= array(17,111);
$arr[1]= array(17,10);
$arr[2]= array(20,111);

$return = subArr($arr);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($return);

function subArr($arr) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $result[$a[0]] += $a[1];
    }
    return $result;
}
```